# AVPlayer HLS live stream level meter (Display FFT Data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, media-player, avplayer

I'm using `AVPlayer` for a radio app using HTTP live streaming. Now I want to implement a level meter for that audio stream. The very best would a level meter showing the different frequencies, but a simple left / right solution would be a great starting point.

I found several examples using `AVAudioPlayer`. But I cannot find a solution for getting the required informations off `AVPlayer`.

Can someone think of a solution for my problem?

**EDIT** I want to create something like this (but nicer)

[image: nice levelmeter]

**EDIT II**

One suggestion was to use `MTAudioProcessingTap` to get the raw audio data. The examples I could find using the `[[[_player currentItem] asset] tracks]` array, which is, in my case, an empty array. Another suggestion was to use `[[_player currentItem] audioMix]` which is `null` for me.

**EDIT III**

After *years* already, there still not seems to be a solution. I did indeed make progress, so I'm sharing it.

During setup, I'm adding a key-value observer to the playerItem:

```
[[[self player] currentItem] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"tracks" options:kNilOptions context:NULL];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)changecontext:(void *)context
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"tracks"] && [[object tracks] count] > 0) {
        for (AVPlayerItemTrack *itemTrack in [object tracks]) {
            AVAssetTrack *track = [itemTrack assetTrack];

            if ([[track mediaType] isEqualToString:AVMediaTypeAudio]) {
                [self addAudioProcessingTap:track];
                break;
            }
        }
}

- (void)addAudioProcessingTap:(AVAssetTrack *)track {
    MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap;
    MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks callbacks;
    callbacks.version = kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0;
    callbacks.clientInfo = (__bridge void *)(self);
    callbacks.init = init;
    callbacks.prepare = prepare;
    callbacks.process = process;
    callbacks.unprepare = unprepare;
    callbacks.finalize = finalise;

    // more tap setup...

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];

    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *inputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:audioTrack];
    [inputParams setAudioTapProcessor:tap];
    [audioMix setInputParameters:@[inputParams]];

    [[[self player] currentItem] setAudioMix:audioMix];
}
```

So far so good. This all works, I could find the right track and setup the inputParams and audioMix etc.
But unfortunately the only callback, that gets called is the init callback. None of the others will fire at any point.

I tried different (kinds of) stream sources, one of them an official Apple HLS stream: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

Comment: what is the need of level meters?,if you are playing live streaming, @Julian

Comment: I'm working on a radio app and my customers designer wanted a level meter for the various frequencies. Like this (but nicer) http://www.oocities.org/henrym24/eq.gif

Comment: Ok, I have worked on live streaming but not on audio visualization like this, I have posted an answer with some example links may you get help. Happy Coding :) @Julian

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109516/record-streaming-audio-from-currently-playing-video-in-avplayer?

Comment: Actually not, thanks. I'm assuming that he streams actual audio files. The callbacks aren't called in case of HLS only. I'll have a deeper look later and commened over there.

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I revisit this almost once a year, but I think there might be no solution at all :(

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert Solved? If yes, can you pls share? If not, did you try AVAudioEngine or some other means? I face the same issue and tried other approaches but no good. There must be a way as some apps can do it (HLS with EQ).

Comment: @Rao sadly no. But it's also been a long time since I actively developed on iOS / tried to accomplish that... I tried a lot of different things, it's possible that more modern APIs offer something alike. Maybe one chance would be routing the audio to a different component. I agree, there *has* to be a way, but all the ones I tried didn't give output for HLS streams

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert Thx for replying! Not a problem. I will share once I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, using an HLS stream with `AVFoundation` doesn't give you any control over the audio tracks. I ran into the same problem trying to mute an HLS stream, which turned out to be impossible.

The only way you could read audio data would be to tap into the `AVAudioSession`.

*EDIT*

You can access the AVAudioSession like this:

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
```

Here's the documentation for [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: How do I access the session?

Comment: Well, that looks quite promising, thanks. Do then use this session (or any of it's properties) as input for the `MTAudioProcessingTap`?

Comment: Good question, but whatever information you need to process audio should be available in there.

Comment: @Simon Germain see my comment to Julian re HLS stream. It is indeed possible to insert MTAudioProcessingTap into a HLS Stream hosted via AVPlayer.

Comment: @MDB983 just to recap that two years later... Are you willing to provide us any detail on _how_ it can be done?

Comment: Unfortunately not on my side. I was never able to figure out anything despite what's written in my question. Surprisingly undiscussed on the internet...

Comment: still need answer how to access meters of avplayer

Comment: @DavidSeek unfortunately not yet. There's a fairly new comment under the OP, which might be worth looking into

Comment: Sorry, dunno why it's actually being downvoted, but so far I wasn't able to achieve my goal by any means... Unfortunately I cannot find the comment @MDB983 was talking about and he also didn't give a hint on his solution so far :/

Answer (score 2):

Measuring audio using `AVPlayer` looks to be an issue that is still ongoing. That being said, I believe that the solution can be reached by combining `AVPlayer` with `AVAudioRecorder`.

While the two classes have seemingly contradictory purposes, there is a work around that allows `AVAudioRecorder` to access the `AVPlayer`'s audio output.

### Player / Recorder

As described in this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403995/playing-video-with-avplayer-and-recording-sound-with-avaudiorecorder-simultaneou), recording the audio of a AVPlayer is possible if you access the **audio route change** using `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange`.

Notice that the audio recording must be started **after** accessing the audio route change. Use the linked stack answer as a reference - it includes more details and necessary code.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Once you have access to the `AVPlayer`'s audio route and are recording, the **measuring** is relatively straightforward.

### Audio Levels

In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692438/measure-microphone-level-in-webrtc-for-ios/45952242#45952242) to a stack question regarding measuring microphone input I describe the steps necessary to access the audio level measurements. Using `AVAudioRecorder` to monitor volume changes is more complex than one would think, so I included a GitHub [project](https://github.com/picciano/iOS-Audio-Recoginzer/blob/master/ARAudioRecognizer.m) that acts as a template for monitoring audio changes while recording.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ **Please Note** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This combination during an HLS live stream is not something that I have tested. This answer is strictly theoretical, so it may take a sound understanding of both classes to work out completely.

Comment: Wow – that sounds like an obvious workaround, once someone describes it, but hard to think of yourself... Many thanks! I'll have to have look, as the question is more than four years old by now (even though I looked into the topic once in awhile). Please give me a few days to work on that – I'll try to revisit this asap. Again, thanks for sharing your idea!

Comment: Of course. Based on the comments on the answer provided, it seemed to me that there are still plenty of others looking for a viable solution. Not to mention, the number of votes/stars your question has received.