# Getting averagePowerForChannel in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

how can i get the `averagePowerForChannel` in `AVPlayer` in order to make an audio visualization on my music app! 
ive already done the visualization part but im stuck in its engine (realtime volume channel).

i know that by using `AVAudioPlayer` it can be done easily using the `.meteringEnabled` Property but for some known reason `AVPlayer` is a must in my app!
im actualy thinking of using `AVAudioPlayer` Alongside with  `AVPlayer` to get the desired result but it sounds kind of messy workaround,
how can that affect performance and stability?
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a way to get averagePowerForChannel for AVPlayer?

Comment: hey i did found a solution but it only work when you playing a non online file, let me know if you need it

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using remote files. Still, I'm interested in your solution.

Comment: this is a working example (on swift 3) it should be easy to follow, https://github.com/Med072356/avplayer

Comment: Hi, have you got any solutions on this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need an audio processor class in combination with AV Foundation to visualize audio samples as well as applying a Core Audio audio unit effect (Bandpass Filter) to the audio data. You can find a [sample by Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html)

Essentially you will need to add an observer to you AVPlayer like the below:

```
// Notifications
let playerItem: AVPlayerItem!  = videoPlayer.currentItem
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "tracks", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context:  nil);

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: videoPlayer.currentItem, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: { (notif: NSNotification) -> Void in
   self.videoPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
   self.videoPlayer.play()
   print("replay")
})
```

Then handle the notification in the overriden method below:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if (object === videoPlayer.currentItem && keyPath == "tracks"){
        if let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = videoPlayer.currentItem {
            if let tracks = playerItem.asset.tracks as? [AVAssetTrack] {
                tapProcessor = MYAudioTapProcessor(AVPlayerItem: playerItem)
                playerItem.audioMix = tapProcessor.audioMix
                tapProcessor.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a link to a [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/techseeko/AVPlayerAudioMeter)

Comment: please provide a fully tested/working solution.
ive stated that i want to use avplayer! ur giving no clue man !

Comment: preferably Swift !

Comment: hey thanks for your response !! as i mention in my post im not planning to use  AVAudioPlayer, the real challenge is to find a way to use  AVPlayer to achieve this kind of thing !!
sorry but ur not getting any reward !! because ive already stated that i know how to do it in  AVAudioPlayer.
PS: You are using AVAudioPlayer

Comment: @MedAbida did you check the link above?

Comment: have you tested the code you provided ? its giving me an error no matter what i tried 
(Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11)

Comment: I have changed the link in the answer above after taking the liberty to make a couple of changes to the original demo to help you run the project. Use this project here made especially for your needs... https://github.com/techseeko/AVPlayerAudioMeter

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13524663)

Comment: @TechSeeko easy mate ! we are not starting a debate on what's wrong and what's right arent we ?
providing a link without any explanation or even a single word on how things could be done is not the purpose of SO! its all about sharing knowledge here!
anyway, thanks for your help ! ill check the link and report back !

Comment: @SurvivalMachine Done, added some information and provided a link to an Apple sample just to make sure pieces of the answer will not be removed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I have an issue with `AVPlayer` visualisation for about two years. In my case it involves HLS live streaming, in that case, you won't get it running, as of my knowledge.

**EDIT** This will not let you access the `averagePowerForChannel:` method, but you will get access to the raw data and with for example FFT get the desired information.

I got it working with local playback, though. You basically wait for the players player item to have a track up and running. At that point you will need to patch an `MTAudioProcessingTap` into the audio mix.

The processing tap will run callbacks you specify in which you will be able to compute the raw audio data as you need.

Here is a quick example (sorry for heaving it in ObjC, though):

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaToolbox/MediaToolbox.h>

void init(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, void *clientInfo, void **tapStorageOut) {};
void finalize(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap) {};
void prepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount maxFrames, const AudioStreamBasicDescription *processingFormat) {};
void unprepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap) {};
void process(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount numberFrames, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags, AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut, CMItemCount *numberFramesOut, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut) {};

- (void)play {
    // player and item setup ...

    [[[self player] currentItem] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"tracks" options:kNilOptions context:NULL];
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)changecontext:(void *)context
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"tracks"] && [[object tracks] count] > 0) {
        for (AVPlayerItemTrack *itemTrack in [object tracks]) {
            AVAssetTrack *track = [itemTrack assetTrack];

            if ([[track mediaType] isEqualToString:AVMediaTypeAudio]) {
                [self addAudioProcessingTap:track];
                break;
            }
        }
}

- (void)addAudioProcessingTap:(AVAssetTrack *)track {
    MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap;
    MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks callbacks;
    callbacks.version = kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0;
    callbacks.clientInfo = (__bridge void *)(self);
    callbacks.init = init;
    callbacks.prepare = prepare;
    callbacks.process = process;
    callbacks.unprepare = unprepare;
    callbacks.finalize = finalise;

    OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks, kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap);

    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:err userInfo:nil]);
        return;
    }

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];

    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *inputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:audioTrack];
    [inputParams setAudioTapProcessor:tap];
    [audioMix setInputParameters:@[inputParams]];

    [[[self player] currentItem] setAudioMix:audioMix];
}
```

There is some discussion going on over on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403584/avplayer-hls-live-stream-level-meter-display-fft-data) from over two years ago, so make sure to check it out as well.

Comment: thanks, objective-c is ok too.
i found your old post when searching for a solution ! the only problem is that im not using HLS live streaming.
it all about *.audio(mp3/wav/etc..) files! 
im working on a solution where i cache the file and save it as mp3 file then update the visualisation.
ill test your code and see if it can help.

Comment: That's fine, because my stuff does not work with streaming *but* with local files (what you asked for). Also check out my edits, I added more details in the code as well!

Comment: it turns out that MTAudioProcessingTap is not fully compatible with swift.
ill keep on digging and try to implement it using objective-c(my project is in swift) any way, you ll get the reward as soon as it fully works and no further answer were posted! you can still help by providing a swift solution if its possible!

Comment: Bummer. But that reflects the current status and production usability of Swift pretty well. Unfortunately I can't help out with Swift, but I would recommend a simple wrapper class that is easy to bridge to Swift (i.e. Provide a better callback interface, ...). You can use the contexts to get your class instance in any of thr callbacks, so it shouldn't be too hard to accomplish

Comment: absolutely! swift isnt (at least for now) fully waterproof. im working on a clss to bridge it to swift ! ill let you know when its ready ! ill post it here for refrence ! thanks.

Comment: @MedAbida how is `MTAudioProcessingTap` not compatible with swift?

Comment: @MedAbida I'd like to know the same... It's simply a C interface which seems to be available in Swift. Although, it looks like there are some difficulties. Here is an example implementation I found: https://github.com/gchilds/MTAudioProcessingTap-in-Swift/blob/master/swift%20tap/AppDelegate.swift