# AVPlayer averagePower(forChannel:)

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avasset, avplayeritem

I'm using an `AVPlayer` and I'm looking for the `averagePower(forChannel:)` equivalent of `AVAudioPlayer` and `AVAudioRecorder`. I need it to make some visual audio animations.

Comment: hopefully this link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39166034/getting-averagepowerforchannel-in-avplayer

Comment: Thanks @baridcse but I've already seen this link and unfortunately it's not helping

Comment: @MarieDm, found anyway? I need also to show visual audio animations for a song that is streamed from URL.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj Unfortunately no, I implemented `AVAudioPlayer` for audio files.

Comment: I think you can use `AVAssetReader` to analyse every frame of the file but I did not look into it.

Comment: @MarieDm Hi! Did you find solution for this problem?

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev sorry it was a long time ago I don't remember.