# Measure microphone level in WebRTC for iOS

Tags: ios, audio, webrtc

I have a WebRTC iOS application.
There I have `AVAudioSession` and `RTCAudioSource`.
I need to detect when a microphone starts receiving loud sounds (like when a person starts speaking) similar to what [hark](https://github.com/otalk/hark) does in the browser with [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext).
How can I detect it or get something that resembles stream that can be measured like `AVCaptureAudioChannel` or `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`?

Comment: Assuming that you will be making webrtc calls, why don't you consider using peerconnection->getStats() method and use `audioInputLevel` stats parameter? This parameter gives input audio level and you can use the same to know the intensity of the sound.

Comment: @manishg unfortunately I don't have this API. In which version was it introduced? This [doxygen](http://webrtc.b0.upaiyun.com/da/d93/class_r_t_c_peer_connection.html) knows nothing about it neither.

Comment: It's been there from long time. You can check the header files

Comment: Regarding WebRTC stats, check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCStatsReport

Comment: @manishg Yes, that peer connections RTLegacy stats gave the audio input level as well as the output level too. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 2):

After using `AVAudioSession` to request permission to record audio, I would recommending using **AVAudioRecorder.** It is a fairly straightforward class and is as simple as:

- Create an instance of `AVAudioRecorder`
- Call the method `prepareToRecord` on the instance
- Enable the sound metering function using the method `meteringEnabled`

After enabling the recording, you can access the recording volume ***measurement*** using the method `averagePowerForChannel:`.

*You may want to read Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder?language=objc)*

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ `N O T E` ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I am not familiar with the WebRTC framework/functionality, but the **AVAudioRecorder** class will provide you with the ability to **measure** the audio input during a recording.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ `S A M P L E` ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I've included a GitHub [sample project](https://github.com/picciano/iOS-Audio-Recoginzer/blob/master/ARAudioRecognizer.m) that I've used in the past. It is setup to detect sensitivity of the audio using the AVAudioRecorder class that I've described.

Comment: The problem is that for WebRTC audio track is requested through internal method: `RTCAudioTrack *audioTrack = [self.peerConnectionFactory audioTrackWithTrackId:trackId];` and I don't create any audio recorders.