# javascript Audio visualisation in Safari not working for internet radio streams (Icecast/shoutcast)

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api, icecast

Can anybody help me to check why this code is not working in Safari (osx)?
The audio is is playing, but no visualisation.
I tried all the hints I found, but still no luck.
Need to mention it's working fine in Chrome (osx)
Thanks a lot for help

```
function getDataFromAudio() {
  var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize / 2);
  var timeByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize / 2);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData);
  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(timeByteData);
  return { f: freqByteData, t: timeByteData }; // array of all 1024 levels
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mrvii/pen/ExERxgo)

To be more precise, the visualisation and getByteFrequencyData/getByteTimeDomainData does not work for internet radios (Icecast/shoutcast), but works for single remote mp3.

1. [CodePen - audio stream test icecast - not working in Safari](https://codepen.io/mrvii/pen/wvmXJVj)
2. [CodePen - audio stream
   test mp3 - working in Safari](https://codepen.io/mrvii/pen/PoRamqQ)

Comment: Do you get any errors in the dev tools?

Comment: no error. just the console messages I wanted to see.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually a bug in Safari.

The analyzer data is all zeroes, which is typical if there's a CORS problem.  Yet, I don't see any issue with the response headers from that Icecast stream.  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `*` which is the same as the GitHub.io stream.

The only two meaningful differences in the responses that I see:

- The MP3 file has the erroneous `Content-Type` of `audio/mp3`.  (It should be `audio/mpeg`.)
- Safari requests ICY-style metadata from the stream.

I suspect Safari is handing the stream off to some other component, and its output cannot be captured with the MediaElementSourceNode.

Comment: Seems like you're right. According to the comments on the linked Q/A the problem would come from AVPlayer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403584/avplayer-hls-live-stream-level-meter-display-fft-data